# Examples of Synthesized Sound Effects

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, synthesis

This question was asked a few years back and I actually supplied one of the answers ([Examples of subtractive analog synthesis in sound design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/13350/examples-of-substractive-analog-synthesis-in-sound-design)).  I'm looking to expand on this and want to know of any examples of designed sound effects (for visual content) that have been created with any form of synthesis (not just subtractive).  Interested in recent (last 10 years) examples as many that I already have are older (Star Wars, Star Trek, Tron, Forbidden Planet, Dr Who, Apocalypse Now, etc.). I am particularly interested in examples from non-scifi content and any examples from non-movie/TV content (games, radio, theatre, etc.)  BTW I am aware of Procedural Audio and think I have this area covered.

I should also say  that I am after some form of corroboration for the examples, rather than just "it sounds like synthesis" answers.  This could be first hand experience (I'm hoping there are still some professional sound designers here?), interviews, articles or some other form of reference.  I'm happy to do the leg-work and find these, if I'm pointed in the right direction.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: In case anyone else is interested in this area, the following article briefly mentions the voice of BB-8 from Star Wars: The Force Awakens, which was synthesised and then they gave J.J. Abrams a mechanism to generate expressions and articulations, via a touch-screen tablet.  http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/envelope/la-en-craft-star-wars-sound-20160204-story.html

Comment: Hi @Bit Depth, I can't think of any recent examples of this in my field (sound design for film), however I'm sure there are plenty of designers who count analog synths among the tools at their disposal. I have been known  to use a Moog from time to time (albeit an emulator and not an physical uint) because I love the fatness and depth. Also, starting with something as simple as a square or sawtooth wave and designing from there is another method I know some designers like to employ.

Comment: @JayJennings thanks for the response.  I'd hoped there might be some example in those excellent films you do.  Thanks anyway.  I appreciate your time.